# Regex in Ruby: expression not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm having trouble with a regex in Ruby (on Rails). I'm relatively new to this.

The test string is:
http://www.xyz.com/017010830343?$ProdLarge$

I am trying to remove "$ProdLarge$".  In other words, the $ signs and anything between.

My regular expression is:
\$\w+\$

Rubular says my expression is ok. http://rubular.com/r/NDDQxKVraK

But when I run my code, the app says it isn't finding a match. Code below:

```
some_array.each do |x|
   logger.debug "scan #{x.scan('\$\w+\$')}"
   logger.debug "String? #{x.instance_of?(String)}"

   x.gsub!('\$\w+\$','scl=1')

   ...
```

My logger debug line shows a result of "[]". String is confirmed as being true. And the gsub line has no effect.

What do I need to correct?

Comment: You're passing a string *containing* a regex instead of an actual regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `/regex/` instead of `'regex'`:

```
> "http://www.xyz.com/017010830343?$ProdLarge$".gsub(/\$\w+\$/, 'scl=1')
=> "http://www.xyz.com/017010830343?scl=1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a regex for this task, use a tool designed for it, [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html). To remove the query:

```
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse('http://www.xyz.com/017010830343?$ProdLarge$')
url.query = nil

puts url.to_s
=> http://www.xyz.com/017010830343
```

To change to a different query use this instead of `url.query = nil`:

```
url.query = 'scl=1'

puts url.to_s
=> http://www.xyz.com/017010830343?scl=1
```

URI will automatically encode values if necessary, saving you the trouble. If you need even more URL management power, look at [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: thanks. I didn't realize URI was so handy. In this particular app, I believe need to use some form of regex because the queries can actually get a lot more complex than the example here. But I'll apply this somewhere.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show accurate examples of what you're up against. Add your other examples to your original question by editing it.